# gparted moving unallocated to 1st partition

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

[image]

How can I assign unnalocated space to 1st partition `/dev/sda1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your extended (swap space) to the end of unallocated space and then resize `sda1`. By moving I mean you could simply delete it, resize `sda1` and then create the swap space at the end of the disk.

Comment: Better to let gparted move it rather than delete and recreate it yourself, which will then require you to update the uuid in fstab.

Comment: But how to move it ? its not possible